# Discrete Random variable question

Tags: probability

Show that a variable X is a discrete random variable if X is the number of fours observed when two dice are rolled together

Comment: Yes $X$ is discrete for the good reason that it is integer-valued, that's all...

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,5,6\}^2$, $\mathcal F = 2^\Omega$, and define $\mathbb P:\mathcal F\to\mathbb R$ by $$\mathbb P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|\mathcal F|}.$$
The map $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is given by 
$$
X((\omega_1, \omega_2) = 
\begin{cases}
0,& \omega_1 \ne 4 \text{ and } \omega_2 \ne 4\\
1,& \omega_1 = 4 \text{ and } \omega_2 \ne 4, \text{ or } \omega_1 \ne 4 \text{ and } \omega_2 =4\\
2,& (\omega_1,\omega_2) = (4,4).
\end{cases}
$$
Since $X^{-1}(\{0\})$, $X^{-1}(\{1\})$, and $X^{-1}(\{2\})$ are subsets of $\Omega$, it follows that $X$ is Borel-measurable and therefore a random variable. Moreover, we have $$\mathbb P(X=0) = \frac{25}{36},\quad \mathbb P(X=1)=\frac5{18},\quad \mathbb P(X=2) = \frac1{36}$$
and hence $\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\in\{0,1,2\}\})$ = 1. We conclude that $X$ is a discrete random variable.